# How do I return all rows of data from min date to the next possible date after current date in date column?

Tags: sql, powerbi-desktop

Consider a table with multiple rows with dates:

```
Date
------   
5/9/2022  
5/27/2022  
4/18/2022  
6/2/2022  
7/1/2022  
6/6/2022  
7/8/2022  
7/6/2022  
7/22/2022  
7/19/2022  
7/11/2022
```

current query is returning all rows `DATE <= GETDATE()+1`
so it would be returning all dates <=7/9/2022 when it actually needs to be <=7/11/22. This being this column never has a date that falls on a weekend or holiday. So on days like Fridays, the query should be trying to pull all rows <= to that coming Monday (the next date in the column or work day). This query has multiple where conditions as well.
`WHERE (_Header.CODE IN ('10', '15')) AND (_Header.LOCATION = '89') AND (_Header.OR_NO > '0') AND (_Header.DATE <= GETDATE()+1)`

Comment: reverse the order and then take the offset of 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would give you the next day in a date field after today. It is a simple common table expression you could use in your query. You would just request all dates be <= to the date that is retrieved from the cte.

```
  with cte(nextDay)
  AS (SELECT TOP 1 cal_date FROM calendar 
  WHERE cal_date > GETDATE() 
  ORDER BY cal_date)
  SELECT * FROM cte
```

Comment: Okay, I was unsure how to use this with my query but I finally found something but I'm not sure its the "best/correct" way but it works. 
`SELECT _Header.DATE, _Header.LOC, _Header.JO_QT, _Header.PT_NU, _Header.JB_NU, _Header.OR_NO, _Header.OR_SE, _Header.AC_CO, 
dbo.PS_TER.FAM_CODE   FROM dbo._HEADER AS _Header INNER JOIN 
dbo.PS_TER ON _Header.PT_NU = dbo.PS_TER.PT_NU 
Join cte b on 1=1 
WHERE (_Header.CODE IN ('10', '15')) AND (_Header.LOC = '89') AND (_Header.OR_NO > '0') AND (_Header.DATE <= b.nextDay)`